# Opportunity stage Report or Dataloader export in salesforce

Tags: reporting, data-loader, data-export, joined-reports

I would like to generate a report on opportunity stage with dates. for example the reports with following columns.

```
Opp Name        Finalist (50%)                       (90%)        Closed Won (100%)
ABC             10/01/2016                           11/01/2016     null
```

If opportunity is directly reached from 50% to 100 % then 90% will shows as blank.
Is it possible to fetch this through dataloader or something.

Comment: what is meant by directly reaching from 50% to 100%? Is that user is changing from 50% to 100% directly or user is updating stage, 50% , 90% and 100%? If you can update your question which this clarification then people could try to guide you

Comment: Thanks for reply santanu. Yes user will change the stage from 50 %, 90 % etc. I would like to know in report which what was the date when opportunity reached at each stage.

Comment: For example user go and update stage from 50 to 100. In this case all between stage for example 75% will show no date as stage was never put on that satage, so report will show null or blank at for stage 75 %

Comment: Thanks Santanu, i tried from history but i was not getting in format where header will show stages and rows will shows dates, like i put in question.

Comment: That type salesforce does not support in out of box, but atleast you can create matrix report to know stage by date

Comment: I am trying, matrix and joined report..will let you know if am successfull :)